# Debugging/testing facebook messenger bot

Tags: facebook, bots, messenger, facebook-messenger

For testing purposes I usually put some logs or debugger into my code, probably as everybody does. To test my bot I would like to do the same but is there even a way to test/debug the messenger bot locally, or do I always have to deploy my tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just fill the webhook url with the url that you use for testing. You can send something to bot, and bot can receive the messages(if you are the administrator of the app). from the received messages you could get your `sender_id`, you can use the sender_id as the recipient and let bot send messages to the recipient. In this step you can just send a POST request independently for testing. After finishing all the testing above, remove the debugging part, it's time to go to app review!

Comment: Hey @iownthegame, thanks for your reply. I do have the sender_id but I don't exactly understand how to use it. You wrote something like the bot should use this id to send messages. To it self? I thought to use Postman as testing tool (Sender). Could you please elaborate a little more on the part how to use the sender_id a little more. Thanks

Comment: Ok, got it. I'm using the whole object and send a post request via postman. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

https://github.com/SonOfSardaar/facebook-send-api-emulator

I wrote that as node application (send api emulation) with angular UI for messenger. this helped me to debug locally.