# How to show web views in messenger

Tags: c#, webview, messaging, botframework, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm following this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/sharing

I've created custom classes :

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
        public class elements
        {
            [JsonProperty]
            public string title { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty]
            public string image_url { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty]
            public string subtitle { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty]
            public default_action default_action { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty]
            public buttons[] buttons { get; set; }
        }
        [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
        public class default_action
        {

            [JsonProperty]
            public string type { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty]
            public string url { get; set; }
        }
        [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
        public class buttons
        {

            [JsonProperty]
            public string type { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty]
            public string url { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty]
            public string title { get; set; }
        }
```

Then, in method :

```
elements e = new elements();

                    e.default_action.type = "web_url";
                    e.default_action.type = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kOkQ4T5WO9E";
                    e.title = "title";

                    List<buttons> list = new List<buttons>();
                    buttons b = new buttons();
                    b.title = "button title";
                    b.type = "web_url";
                    b.url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kOkQ4T5WO9E";
                    list.Add(b);
                    e.buttons = list.ToArray();

                    msg.ChannelData = e;
                    msg.Text = "test";
```

But it throws an error. In bot framework dashboard can't see an issue. 
How to debug this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debugging/testing facebook messenger bot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37399219/debugging-testing-facebook-messenger-bot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to the [Microsoft Bot Framework .NET - Enrich your conversation with Facebook Messengers Webview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v946FUHD_Co) video. It shows you how to utilize the Facebook Messenger extension to provide a Webview experience in your Bot Framework chatbot.

The demo code of the video is [here](https://github.com/jamesemann/intro-to-botframework-12-fbwebview).

Comment: This is off topic. Is it possible to create some template for this ? 
To avoid writing all stuff every time ?

Comment: Yes, you can create classes, put them in a different assembly and reference that assembly in your projects.